# sbuild leading to Can't opendir(): Operation not permitted

Tags: dpkg, debian-policy

I am running `sbuild` command by treating the current debianized source directory as the argument. This is the behaviour when we just run `sbuild` without specifying an argument. I have added the user (in my case `vagrant`) to the sbuild group using

```
sudo sbuild-adduser user vagrant
```

I have copied the file `/usr/share/doc/sbuild/examples/example.sbuildrc` into `~/.sbuildrc`. I have modified certain fields in the `~/.sbuildrc` file such as `$path`, `$pgp_options` and `$distribution` to match what I would normally use while running `dpkg-source` without `sbuild`. These lines in the file are:

```
$pgp_options = ['-us', '-uc'];
```

```
$path = "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games";
```

```
$distribution = 'focal'
```

There is an `orig.tar.gz` file at `../` (one directory above the directory I am running `sbuild` in). The current directory I am in is `skyscraper-0.1` and the tar.gz file is `skyscraper_0.1.orig.tar.gz`. These are the stderr lines from dpkg-source upon running `sbuild` (with no arguments or options):

```
dpkg-source: info: using source format '3.0 (quilt)'
dpkg-source: info: building skyscraper using existing ./skyscraper_0.1.orig.tar.gz
Can't opendir(skyscraper-0.1.orig.WXFTtF/man): Operation not permitted
 at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Source/Patch.pm line 246.
Can't opendir(skyscraper-0.1.orig.WXFTtF/share): Operation not permitted
 at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Source/Patch.pm line 246.
Can't opendir(skyscraper-0.1.orig.WXFTtF/include): Operation not permitted
 at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Source/Patch.pm line 246.
Can't opendir(skyscraper-0.1.orig.WXFTtF/lib): Operation not permitted
 at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Source/Patch.pm line 246.
Can't opendir(skyscraper-0.1.orig.WXFTtF/src): Operation not permitted
 at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Source/Patch.pm line 246.
diff: skyscraper-0.1.orig.WXFTtF/include/utils.h: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'skyscraper-0.1.orig.WXFTtF/man': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'skyscraper-0.1.orig.WXFTtF/share': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'skyscraper-0.1.orig.WXFTtF/include': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'skyscraper-0.1.orig.WXFTtF/lib': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'skyscraper-0.1.orig.WXFTtF/src': Operation not permitted
dpkg-source: error: rm -rf skyscraper-0.1.orig.WXFTtF subprocess returned exit status 1
E: Failed to package source directory /home/vagrant/skyscraper/deb-package/skyscraper-0.1
```

What could be the cause of this? Are there any permissions I need to change?